# Passing Verified Number as CallerId in Twilio API with C#

Tags: c#, twilio

I have following scenario:

1) Application asks the user to input a phone number.

2) Number is verified on the fly using AddOutgoingCallerId.

3) Application store the number in a session.

All this code is written in a web page say:

http://www.mysite.com/CallNumber.aspx

4) Application now use twilio api to initiate call using InitiateOutboundCall.

5) Using  verb Twilio api collects a number and transfers the call to the url mentioned "action" attribute of gather verb.

Imagine it like:

6) Now I want to pass the value stored in session (mentioned in step 3) to be used by http://www.mysite.com/targetpage.aspx.

7) Now even though CallNumber.aspx and targetpage.aspx are on same server, targetpage.aspx always receives session value as null, because call to CallNumber.aspx will be made by a User and call to targetpage.aspx will be made by twilio api server, so there are two different calls.

My ultimate target is to pass the phone number of the user who initiates the call (say Customer1) to the called number, collected by using  verb (say Customer 2) .as callerId.
I am adding dropbox link of the image which shows the scenario:
[DropBox Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/plkuqlopal80zs1/ScreenHunter_02%20Jan.%2010%2023.40.gif)

How can I pass the Customer1's phone number as caller id to Customer 2, as keeping the phone number in session doesn't work (Because calls are initiated from different locations I guess) ?

Comment: As far as I think it can't be done using sessions, as source of calls will be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

You could pass the phone number received by CallReceived.aspx to targetpage.aspx by appending it to targetpage.aspx as a querystring value:

```
var result = client.InitiateOutboundCall("+15555555555","+15556666666","http://www.mysite.com/targetsite.aspx?number=%2B15557777777");
```

Then in targetpage.aspx, you just use the Request object to get the number:

```
string number = request["number"];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Definitely it gave me the idea to solve my issue. Thanks a ton